# Is this a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Could you please solve step by step for f(x)

$$f(x+dx) - f(x) = m^{dx}(f(x) - f(x-dx))\ $$

$dx \to 0$

$m$ is a constant.

The final answer is obvious, but I cannot figure out how to write it up. It is not an assignment to be submitted.

Appreciated.

My approach is 
$f(x+dx)-2f(x)+f(x-dx) = (m^{dx}-1) (f(x)-f(x-dx))$

$f''(x)=((m^{dx}-1)/dx)f'(x)$

Then $f''=\ln(m) f'$ (Many thanks to Ian)

Please let me know if these are correct.

Thanks to all of you again

Comment: $f (x+dx)=f (x)+f'(x)dx,f (x-dx)=f (x)-f'(x) dx$ and $(dx)^2=0$, and in particular $m^{dx}=1+\ln (m) dx $. Using those rules you can get a "standard form" differential equation after dividing out $dx $. But it will be inconsistent in this form, so perhaps second order expansion is required here?

Comment: Sorry the "d" notation was originally in delta symbol.

Comment: So yeah you need second order expansion which gives what you wrote.

Comment: Looks good enough to me.